# Selecting a diode to prevent backfeeding from 5 V to USB-C port

Tags: circuit-design, diodes, voltage-regulator, usb-c

I am making a circuit in which there will be a 12-30 V input reduced to 5 V and a USB-C port.

I wanted to know which diode to use to avoid backfeeding the 5 V into the USB-C port. The diode should be capable of passing at least 500 mA from the USB-C port. The purpose of using the USB-C port while the 12-30V is connected is for debugging and the diode will also help prevent someone from blowing up their computer from backfeeding.Please do not focus on the other issues as I have already posted other questions about them.

Additionally, any insights into potential issues or best practices would be appreciated.

Schematics:
[image: Schematics]

Comment: My question is, why do you even need that? You never said how the device is supposed to work. If the only purpose of the USB connector is to connect to the CP2102, and not to power the whole circuit through USB, because it can't do that anyway as it needs external supply to run the load, why would you even try to power it from USB? Also, Neopixels don't work with 3.3V, in the previous question I already said you need a level shifter to drive 5V devices with 3.3V data.

Comment: *If problem with blue led, change 3.3V to 5V* Nope, the things are not rated to work from 3.3V. 3.7V is the datasheet minimum. You have to power them from 5V so that they'll work as specified (across temperatures, stably enough, etc.). You also have to have logic level translation for the data line to go from 3.3V logic to 5V logic. See the schematic I've provided for you.

Comment: Oups I believe it was meant to be "electronic" and I forgot to remove it. Fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5V rail is only feeding the 3.3V regulator that has a low dropout of about 1V, and the neopixels which work down to 3.7V. Any silicon diode rated for 1000mA minimum will do the job. A 1N4001 (SMD variant is called M1) will do the job just fine, as will do any higher diode in the 1N4001/M1 series, up to 7, i.e. up to 1N4007 or M7. The lower the number, the lower the reverse voltage rating, but all of them are much higher than your application requires, so 1N4001 or M1 will be perfect.

The reworked schematic, with **necessary Neopixel level translation added** is here: https://oshwlab.com/kuba2/701486. I've updated the answer to the question that has the schematic image included as well.

You'd still need to match the reference designators and footprints to the specific parts you've used in the project, I only matched the major part numbers and footprints, not designators etc.

Comment: Is this diode ok? https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Diodes-General-Purpose_MDD-Microdiode-Electronics-M7_C95872.html I cannot seem to find if it is a silicon one.

Comment: @LoicDaigle Yes, it's silicon since the forward voltage at full rated current is above 0.7V (in your case, 1.1V max).

Comment: So i could take it for my use?

Comment: Yes. It is rated for 1A, and it is the SMT equivalent of 1N4007 (hence named M7, M1 would be 1N4001, etc.). You could use a lower M number, all the way down to M1, if available, since they'd have a slightly lower forward voltage drop. But in your application, M7 is fine. I'm also not sure what you have tried to achieve with the autoreset circuit. It's really hard to figure out what you know and what you don't know (nobody can read your mind).

Comment: For the auto reset circuit, I took it from a project by MakerMoekoe and used it in many other projects and it works well. What it does is it automatically puts the ESP32 into "download mode" and automatically resets it when programming.

Comment: @LoicDaigle Makes sense. But ESP32 can be updated via WiFi AFAIK, so no need for buttons and stuff. You just need to add some bootloader code.

Comment: I have the functionality in my code but when the ESP32 is new, I don't think it can be updated by OTA and, if the OTA doesn't work I still have the option to use the USB-C port with autoreset OR with the FTDI232. And that's why it is written "NOT MANDATORY".